# What's the spectrum of $A+\sum \alpha_i A_i$ where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathrm{null}(A_i)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

For $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ consider the linear system $$\mathbf{b}=A\mathbf{x},$$
where $A$ is square. I would like to study the spectral properties of $A+\sum \alpha_i A_i$ for all $A_i$ such that $A_i\mathbf{x}=0$ (I.e., $\mathbf{x}\in\mathrm{null}(A_i)$). In other words, how do the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ change when added to linear combinations of ${A_i}$ such that the resulting matrix leaves the solution of the linear system invariant?

Is there a special name for these matrices or for this problem?

E.g., for $n=3$ we have $\mathbf{x} = (x,y,z)^T\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and the matrices $A_i$ are from the following set:
$$ A_i \in \left\{  \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\  0&0&0\\  -y&x&0\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\  0&0&0\\  -z&0&x\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\  0&0&0\\  0&-z&y\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -y&x&0\\  0&0&0\\  0&0&0\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -z&0&x\\  0&0&0\\  0&0&0\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-z&y\\  0&0&0\\  0&0&0\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\  -y&x&0\\  0&0&0\end {array}\right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\  -z&0&x\\  0&0&0\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&0&0\\  0&-z&y\\  0&0&0\end {array} \right]  \right\} $$

Comment: Are there more hypotheses (e.g. will the list $A_i$ always be finite, or otherwise restricted in some way, e.g. specified in advance as part of the input data)? If only $A$ and $b$ and $x$ are given, and one can make unrestricted choices of the $A_i$, this is the question of how the spectrum varies across $\{A + M: Mx = 0\}$. But the specific list of $A_i$ that you provide as an example (and inclusion of $b$ as an input) makes me wonder if you're pondering something more specialized than that.

Comment: @leslietownes Yes you're correct, my actual problem is a bit more involved! What I really want to know is what linear combinations of $A_i(x)$ can we add to $A(x)$ s.t. the eigenvectors $v$ of $A(x)+\sum \alpha_i A_i(x)$ are independent of $x$. I.e. $\nabla v = 0$. I guess the set $A_i$ can be unrestricted. The list I provided for $n=3$ is what I thought are a basis for all such $A_i$ but I could be mistaken. I guess it boils down to knowing how the spectrum varies across $\{A(x)+A_i(x):A_i(x)x=0\}$, except $A=A(x)$ and is linear in $x$ in each component (as is $A_i=A_i(x)$).  Any thoughts?